# Pinescript - detecting manually opened position / order

Tags: pine-script

Using Pinescript, is it possible to detect a manually opened position / order?

Pinescript manual only refers to positions opened by a strategy, not to manually opened orders.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not possible for now.